# Add Multiple Records to TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

How do you add multiple records (rows) to TableView Through TextField..? 
 
So far i could managed to add a record to TableView through TextField, but when i change TextField values and hit ADD button, it removes previously added record and shows the new Record in TableView.

```
//  Code For Inserting Records to TableView Through TextField  //

 private void Add_details(){
    try {
        String Customer = txtCustomer.getText().trim();
        String Mobile = txtMobile.getText().trim();
        String Item  = txtItem.getText().trim();
        int unit_price = Integer.parseInt(txtUnitPrice.getText().trim());
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText().trim());

       TableItems  t = new TableItems();
       ObservableList <TableItems> curnt_row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

       t.setCustomer(Customer);
       t.setMobile(Mobile);
       t.setItem(Item);
       t.setUnit_price(String.valueOf(unit_price));
       t.setQty(String.valueOf(qty));
       t.setTotal(String.valueOf(total));

       curnt_row.add(t);
       tblItems.setItems(curnt_row);

        col_customer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customer"));
        col_mobile.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("mobile"));
        col_item.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("item"));
        col_qty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("qty"));
        col_unitprice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("unit_price"));
        col_total.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("total"));

    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
// CORDING FOR GET SELECTED ITEM FROM TABLEVIEW   //
// I WANT TO GET ALL ITEMS,
// NOT ONLY SELECTED ITEM SO THAT I COULD PERFORM BATCH INSERTION

      private void Get_table_values(){
          /*  LAMDA EXPRESSION                 */
        tblItems.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener
            ((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
         if (newSelection != null) {
            TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tblItems.getSelectionModel();
            ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
            TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
            Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newSelection);
            String S_value = val.toString();
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the entire `items` list, instead of simply adding a single item. The new list starts empty and the only item you add is the one created in the `Add_details` method. Add the items the existing list instead:

```
private final ObservableList <TableItems> curnt_row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

...

// TableView initialisation
tblItems.setItems(curnt_row);

col_customer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customer"));
col_mobile.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("mobile"));
col_item.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("item"));
col_qty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("qty"));
col_unitprice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("unit_price"));
col_total.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("total"));

...

private void Add_details(){
    try {
        String Customer = txtCustomer.getText().trim();
        String Mobile = txtMobile.getText().trim();
        String Item  = txtItem.getText().trim();
        int unit_price = Integer.parseInt(txtUnitPrice.getText().trim());
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText().trim());

       TableItems  t = new TableItems();

       t.setCustomer(Customer);
       t.setMobile(Mobile);
       t.setItem(Item);
       t.setUnit_price(String.valueOf(unit_price));
       t.setQty(String.valueOf(qty));
       t.setTotal(String.valueOf(total));

       curnt_row.add(t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For getting all items, simply use `getItems` or use the list you know is assigned to the `items` property, e.g. in the above example the `curnt_row` field.

Comment: Shame on me. Problem Solved. Thank You..!